# why is my processes in task manager showing ports like 100028,103904 etc ? I know only 65535 are possible in any windows system

Tags: port, pid

I am on W10 x64. This is unusual . I haven't seen port number that high .I know only 65535 are possible in any windows system. it is happening from today ( I have rebooted several times). Is it because of malware/spyware ? I am attaching a screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 4):

PID stands for **Process ID** and is not the port number a process may be listening on.

Comment: aren't port numbers and pid same ? any pid over 66000 possible mate ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868218/what-is-the-maximum-process-id-on-windows shows an answer as to how PIDs can become much higher than 66000 - they can go into the hundreds of thousands and seem to only be limited by memory

Comment: but before today I have never seen that high pid

Comment: Windows – and Linux, too – used to limit PIDs to 16 bits, but the limit has been raised.

Answer (score 2):

A port is an opening in a communication protocol as TCP or UDP. It is a door opened to let a process communicate with the outside world.

A PID or Process ID is the number the system assigned to the process. Usually is consecutive so you will find that the lowest values are process that started first and the highest are related to process that started later.

Comment: so those high pid are ok ? I have never seen that before today

Comment: @smr Some program at some moment probably created tens of thousands of processes. Could be that the program is attempting to start a process which fails and it keep retrying the action.

Comment: @smr reboot and check the PID in *Task Manager*. You can sort by *PID* so it could be easy to check if it happens always or ocassionaly.

Comment: PIDs on some systems (OpenBSD) are random.

Comment: no it is happening from today ( I have rebooted several times) . Is there malware/spyware ?

Answer (score 0):

A port is basically a TCP / UDP connection that allows communication either inbound outbound or both depending on how your firewall is configured.

A PID or Process ID is a number assigned by your operating system to processes. Windows tends to go consecutively but once a PID is used Windows will not reuse until a reboot takes place. As @Kusalananda pointed out some operating systems OpenBSD as the example do randomly assign PID's however Windows does not.

To view a list of all of the current PID's click on the "Details" tab.
To view a list of all currently connect ports, open CMD and type netstat.

[image: Task Manager Displaying PID's In Order.]
[image: NetStat run from CMD.]